# Collapsing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table below:

I would like to collapse Code_1 and Code_2 columns based on ID and Date. Based on what I have found online, I have tried the below snippet of code but it does not seem to be working.

`df= df.groupby(['ID','Date']).agg(''.join)`

**DF:**

| ID | Date | Count_Code1 | Count_Code2 | Code_1 | Code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-02 | 90 | 0 | AAAA | NaN |
| A1 | 2022-02-02 | 0 | 50 | NaN | BBBB |
| A1 | 2022-03-14 | 34 | 0 | AAAA | NaN |
| C1 | 2022-04-20 | 0 | 13 | NaN | BBBB |
| C1 | 2022-04-20 | 15 | 0 | AAAA | NaN |

**Desired output:**

| ID | Date | Count_Code1 | Count_Code2 | Code_1 | Code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-02 | 90 | 50 | AAAA | BBBB |
| A1 | 2022-03-14 | 34 | 0 | AAAA | NaN |
| C1 | 2022-04-20 | 15 | 13 | AAAA | BBBB |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# groupby and take the group's max
df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).max()
```

```
    ID  Date       Code_1   Code_2
0   A1  2022-02-02  AAAA    BBBB
1   A1  2022-03-14  AAAA    0
2   C1  2022-04-20  AAAA    BBBB
```

Alternate Solution

```
# replace 0 with null, and ffill, bfill null values on grouped rows
# groupby drops the grouped on keys, so, concat them back
# finally drop the duplicates

pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2], 
         df.replace(0, np.nan).groupby(['ID', 'Date'], as_index=False ).ffill().bfill()],
         axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

```
ID  Date    Count_Code1     Count_Code2     Code_1  Code_2
0   A1  2022-02-02  90.0    50.0    AAAA    BBBB
2   A1  2022-03-14  34.0    13.0    AAAA    BBBB
3   C1  2022-04-20  15.0    13.0    AAAA    BBBB
```

Comment: Hi Naveed, this works really well. Unfortunately I made a mistake in a the original post and had to make a small edit (added two columns). I am trying your above code and it works but not when I include the two new columns (Count_Code1 and Count_Code2)

Comment: @TrevorM, added an alternate solution